# accessing object property from function within same object

Tags: javascript, oop, node.js, express

What I'm trying to do here is access the `context` property (or `context.settings`, more specifically) from within the `ready` function in the same object. I'm not sure what the correct syntax is to do this.

here's the code:

```
module.exports = {
    context: {
        settings: require('./settings')
    },
    listen: function(callback) {
      listen(context.settings.http.port);
      callback(null);
    },
    ready: function (err) {
      if (err)
      {
        throw err;
      }
      console.log("Ready and listening at http://localhost:" + context.settings.http.port);
    }
};
```

just for clarification, I'm referring to the line `console.log("Ready and listening at http://localhost:" + context.settings.http.port);`

Edit: a bit more context (ha)

I did try `this.context.settings.http.port`, but I get
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined`.

Here's the contents of `settings.js`, just to be sure...

```
module.exports = { 
  db: {
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 27017,
    name: 'jsblogdemo'
  },
  http: {
    port: 3000
  }
};
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another possibility is this:

```
module.exports = (function() {
    var context = {
        settings: require('./settings')
    },
    listen = function(callback) {
      listen(context.settings.http.port);
      callback(null);
    },
    ready = function (err) {
      if (err)
      {
        throw err;
      }
      console.log("Ready and listening at http://localhost:" + 
                    context.settings.http.port);
    };

    return {
        // context: context, // needed?
        listen: listen,
        ready: ready
    };
}());
```

Then the functions have local access to the `context` object without any worries about how they're called.  And the `context` object can be kept entirely private if you like.

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a single, static object, you could just do:

```
module.exports.context.settings
```

If you want a permanently bound `this`, use `.bind()`.

```
module.exports = {
    context: {
        settings: require('./settings')
    }
}
module.exports.listen = function(callback) {
    listen(this.context.settings.http.port);
    callback(null);
}.bind(module.exports);

module.exports.ready = function (err) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    console.log("Ready and listening at http://localhost:" + this.context.settings.http.port);
}.bind(module.exports);
```

Comment: Added some more context to main post

Comment: works fine when they're defined separately as you did in the second example - thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

As long as a method isn't being bound to another context by `call` or `apply`, `this` refers to the current object context. For instance, use:

```
console.log(this.context.settings.http.port);
```

To print the listening port.